# What collection class should I use?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

At the moment, my iPhone app uses NSMutableArrays to hold onto NSStrings. I have more information I want to associate with each entry in each array. For example, previously I had just one thing to put in Array1[0], a string. Now, however, along with the string I want to associate another string and an integer. I guess something like:

old: [string]

new [string, string, integer]

I was thinking of using a dictionary but I'm not really sure if it's right. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements in your `NSArray` could be dictionaries, C `structs`, or Objective-C objects.

A dictionary works, but it can be cumbersome if you’re storing primitive data type values (need to be boxed, e.g. `NSNumber`) or there’s potential for extending data in deeper levels (dictionary containing a dictionary containing another dictionary). Also, dictionary objects are not implicitly typed.

A C `struct` works but it also needs boxing, and you don’t benefit from Cocoa collection semantics with regard to memory management — you have to do that on your own. Also, there’s no implicit support for `copy/retain` semantics for `struct` members.

I usually declare an Objective-C class for aggregate data types that are to be stored in collections such as `NSArray`. In your case, something like

```
@interface MyData : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *firstString;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *secondString;
@property (assign) NSInteger integer;
@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries are key-value pairs, so they won't fit the bill here. You can use an array containing arrays, or an array containing a custom class with your strings and integer values.

Answer (score 1):

You choose an Array if you just want a collection and need to iterate over that collection.

You choose a Dictionary if you want to look things up by a key other than the index of the entry.

This is all generally speaking, of course, but you haven't indicated any reason you need to use a Dictionary.

Remember, you can create a class that has two strings and an integer in it, and put objects of that type into an array.